# Stealing wheelEvents from a QScrollArea

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to put my custom widget in a QScrollArea, but in my custom widget, I reimplemented wheelEvent(e) and it never gets called.

I'm fine with the scroll area not having its mouse wheel scrolling functionality. I just need those wheelEvents to call my handler. I tried handling the events out at the level of the main window but I only got them when the scroll widget was at one of its extremes and couldn't have moved any further anyways, I need all of them.

Heres a simplified version of my code:

```
class custom(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(custom, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        print "Custom Widget's wheelEvent Handler"

class mainw(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainw, self).__init__(parent)
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        self.tw = thread_widget(scroll)
        scroll.setWidget(self.tw)
        self.setCentralWidget(scroll)

    def wheelEvent(self,event):
        print "Main Window's wheelEvent Handler"
```

Can someone explain to me how it is determined which event handler gets the events in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that its got something to do with the installEventFilter method of QObject, but I couldn't get the example to work so I said to hell with this and changed my plan completely.

problem solved

Comment: No, problem not solved at all... I ended up here, having the same problem, and there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a eventFilter in your custom class

```
class custom(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(custom, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, qobject, qevent):
        qtype = qevent.type()
        if qtype == QEvent.Wheel:
            ... wheel event logic
            return True
        # parents event handler for all other events
        return super(custom,self).eventFilter(qobject, qevent)
```